# Google XML Sitemaps plugin

Tags: plugin-sitemap

I would like to know that do we have Google XML Sitemaps plugin for Craft CMS. If yes is there an tutorial that how I can use it. I would like to use it for SEO purpose so that Google can easily crawl my website. A short explanation or video tutorial would be really nice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are several plugins that can dynamically generate XML sitemaps for you on your Craft CMS site.

Note that Google XML Sitemaps are not specific to Google. Google supports the [standard sitemap protocol](https://www.sitemaps.org/index.html) which is also used by Microsoft and Yahoo!.

I'll highlight two commercial plugins that support generating sitemaps for all native URL-Enabled Content which includes Entries, Categories, and Commerce Products:

- [Sitemap](https://www.putyourlightson.net/craft-sitemap) - Sitemap by Put Your Lights on is a plugin that focuses specifically on creating an XML sitemap for you.
- [Sprout SEO](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/seo/docs/getting-started/sitemap) - Sprout SEO is a more comprehensive plugin for a wider range of SEO needs, which includes search, social sharing, sitemaps, and redirects. Sprout SEO will generate an XML sitemap for you and supports large sitemaps, multi-regional, and multilingual sitemaps. Sprout is also extensible and developers can add Sitemap support for custom URL-Enabled Sections.

There are also several other free sitemap plugins. A [search for 'sitemap'](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins?q=sitemap&) in the plugin directory on Straight Up Craft can point you in the direction of several of those.